# Create debian package that installs another debian package (not from repository)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I would like to know if it is possible to have a debian package that installs another package as dependency which is not available from debian/ubuntu repositories.

So lets say I have a package `A.deb` which depends on `B.deb` but `B.deb` is not available in any repository. Both `A.deb` and `B.deb` are available only on local hard disk. Is there a way to install `A.deb` (for example with `apt install ./A.deb`) such that it will automatically also install `B.deb`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a local tivial Repository. Place both A.deb and B.deb inside it.
* Create a folder Repo.
* Copy all .deb files inside it.
* Now create `Packages` index file.

```
$ dpkg-scanpackages Repo > Repo/Packages
$ gzip -c Repo/Package > Repo/Packages.gz
```

- Create entry for the Repo in sources.list.

  ```
  $ mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d

  $ touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Repo.list

  $ echo "deb [trusted=yes] file:/Repo /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Repo.list
  ```

> If this shows missing InRelease file or Release.gpg file use apt-get.

Now apt will search for missing dependencies in your Personal Repo also.
And if A.deb depends on B.deb it will install it.

> If you want to create a package to download and install various packages from different locations. May be you can use **Debian preinst, postinst, prerm, and postrm scripts**.
>
> > **7.6 What is a Debian preinst, postinst, prerm, and postrm script?**
> >
> > > These files are executable scripts which are automatically run before  or  after a package is installed or removed. Along with a file named  control, all of these files are part of the "control" section of a Debian archive file.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is an interesting approach - I will take a closer look at it. Do you know if there is a way to install the `B.deb` independent from dependency management, during installation of `A.deb`? I am thinking of running a small script as post install step to install the `B.deb` package.

Comment: The second part gives you an idea about that. e.g. If I wanted to install vivaldi and along with it also install widevine, I will just unpack the debian package make changes to it, repackage it & the install it. Vivaldi developers use this to add their key to apt and add entry to sources.list file.